# How can i bind a property of an object inner another object in Angular?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a string object property it is inside an object via input field, but when I write inside it, it will return "Cannot read property 'key1' of undefined".

[StackBlitz example project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-binding-with-inner-object)

Comment: At the moment only the type is defined. You need to initialize it to bind to it in the template: `text: test = { obj1: {key1: ''}};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Text object from

```
text: test = {};
```

to

```
text: test = {
    obj1: {
      
    }
  };
```

**Because for a key it can create when value is entered, but for a object like obj1, you need to defined it for accessing any key.**